# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, axios, lets-encrypt

I am building an app in `react-native` and using `axios package` for `post` request. I get the error when axios post request in `react-native` android app. `SSL` certificate is signed with letsencrypt.

`Https` request is working with React-Native 0.47.2 but after upgrading to React-Native 0.55.0 it gives the certificate error.

Certificate is working in both desktop and mobile browsers as well as on application web portal but not working in android app.

**Versions**
android: 8.0.0
React Native: 0.55.0

**Error**

> "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found."

Answer (score 3):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain><!-- Debug port -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">abc.online</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/abc"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This works for me, 10.0.2.2 is the default number for the emulator to communicate with localhost on your machine. If you are using your phone, it should be another IP address.

[image]

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: how can I get .cer file?

Comment: @PoojaRajendranC - Export the SSL certificate from your hosting (generally via Control Panel) then use the OpenSSL executable (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe`) to transform the file into a .CER extension.

Comment: @Ming Li you sre mentioning a subdomain and setting it to the emulator (10.0.2.2). What does it mean. I mean what about the production build? We are not running that on a single emulator. So what does this exactly mean

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using the following solution.

From Android 9(Pie) we need to set networkSecurityConfig into AndroidManifast.xml

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

</application>
```

Now Create a new xml resource file with the name `network_security_config.xml` into `value/xml` folder. This Configuration applies to the base configuration, or the default security configuration, of the app and disables all clear text traffic.

```
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">172.16.33.1</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

For more information, you check the following links

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/#3

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of that exception is that the domain name that you have used is stg server means it has private dns.
**Solution 1**
So in that case ask your server guy to make a certificate file with ext. **.cert** for you. And after that install it on your device and then add dns1 and dns2 to your wifi.

**Solution 2**
Instead of using domain name as url use ip address of your server.it may solve this problem too

Comment: The meaning of that exception is that the signer of the certificate is not trusted by this client. Nothing to do with DNS whatsoever.